# Search a list of objects using object attributes

Tags: c#, oop, search

I am developing a software for managing members for a club.I created an offline search function that takes 3 parameters which are object attributes and returns a list of Members.

**Member class has :**

```
String name;
String email;
String telephone;
```

search method :

```
public static List<Member> Search(String name, String email, String telephone,String username)
```

The method uses at least one of the attributes to search. How can I make it work on 1 attribute , 2 , or 3 in case the user knows the name, email, and telephone of the Members. I was doing this :

```
if (name  != String.Empty) && email != String.Empty) && telephone != String.Empty))
{
   if (Member.FirstName.Equals(name) && Member.Email.Equals(email) && Member.Telephone.Equals(telephone))                            
       members_list.Add(Member.);
}
else if(name.Length > 0 && (email != String.Empty && telephone != String.Empty))
{
    ...
    ...
    ...etc
}
```

In sql it is quite easy

```
 WHERE (FirstName = @FirstName or @FirstName is null)
AND (Email = @Email or @Email is null)
AND (Username =@Username or @Username is null)
AND (Telephone =@Telephone or @Telephone is null)
```

But in offline mode, it is not that simple
Any suggestions for a more efficient way ?

Comment: Why is your approach inefficient, does it work?

Comment: yes , but I think it is not smart enough , there should be a better algorithm, I need the method to search whether you give it one input , 2 , or 3

Comment: You could make it more readable, instead of `!(name.Equals(String.Empty)` use `name != ""`

Comment: As the code is working rather post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinQ to accomplish what you want. It has similiar to you SQL-like syntax:

```
public List<Member> Search(string name, string email, string telephone, string username, List<Member> source)
    {
        var query = from s in source
                    where (((s.name == name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                        && ((s.email == email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                        && ((s.telephone == telephone) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
                        && ((s.username == username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)))
                    select s;

        return query.ToList();
    }

    public class Member
    {
        public String username;
        public String name;
        public String email;
        public String telephone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Member> members = GetAllMembers(); // collection of all members
var query = members.Select(m => m); // query without any filter conditions
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) { // null or "" don't want filter
    query = query.Where(m => m.Name == name); // we want filter by name
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) {
    query = query.Where(m => m.EMail == email); // we want filter by email
}
// ... other filter conditions
var result = query.ToList(); // collection of filtered members
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to make a function for that, to reduce duplicate code and improve readibiliy.

The function name can be cheesy, but I can't resist it :)

```
private bool AllOrNothingEquals(string memberValue, string filterValue)
{
       return string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue) || memberValue.Equals(filterValue); 
}
```

And the usage (with a sprinkle of good practices for readibility):

```
bool validTelephone = AllOrNothingEquals(Member.Telephone, telephone);
bool validName = AllOrNothingEquals(Member.Name, name);
bool validEmail = AllOrNothingEquals(Member.Email, email);

if(validTelephone && validEmail && validName)
{
    //Is it valid
}
else
{
    //NotReally
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || Member.FirstName == name) && 
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || Member.Email == email)) //etc
{
  // do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that you're performing an *offline search*, I understand you want to query an in-memory `IEnumerable<T>` like `List<T>` (i.e. *you're using LINQ-to-Objects*).

Actually there's a solution which simplifies the issue: don't accept the values, but a delegate which already specifies the criteria:

```
List<Member> members = new List<Member>();

public static List<Member> Search(Func<Member, bool> criteria)
{
    IEnumerable<Member> result = members.Where(criteria);

    // Do other stuff, manipulate results...

    return result;
}
```

Now simply call `Search(member => member.FirstName == "Matias")` or `Search(member => member.FirstName == "Matias" && member.Email == "matias@matias.matias")` (or any other regular C# conditional!).

Answer (score -1):

Can you use that :

```
if((name != string.Empty && Member.FirstName.IndexOf(name) > -1) ||
    (email != string.Empty && Member.Email.IndexOf(email) > -1) ||
    (telephone!= string.Empty && Member.Telephone.IndexOf(telephone) > -1))
{
    //Found someone
}
else
{
    //Not found
}
```

In this code you search on the three parameters without being to rigid on the research algorythm. You can avoid one or more of the parameters.

Comment: Your solution will throw an exception if  one or many Member properties are not initialized

Comment: You're right. You can add a Member.FirstName != null but I assume everything is already init.